# Can Haskell [easily] do COM?

Tags: haskell, com

Alright, so I don't really know much about COM. What I do know is that if you write code in one of the Microsoft-sponsored programming languages, then you can write something like 3 lines of code to launch Excel, open a blank workbook, stuff some data into the cells and tell Excel to graph it. But I have no idea how this black magic actually works; all I know is that it's related to COM somehow.

Is it possible to do this kind of thing with Haskell? Is it "easy", or is it going to be hellishly difficult? Because if it's easy, I might try and get this to work, but if it's really hard, there are simpler ways to make Excel graph things...

I'm aware that you don't actually *need* to learn COM just to graph stuff. (E.g., I could use GraphVis or GNUplot, or Google Chart, or write a small Cairo function, or...) I'm interested in how easy or hard it is to do COM with Haskell, and this is just a motivating example.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how easy it is to interface with COM or how easy it is to build a COM-like system within Haskell?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez sounds like the former.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I'm interested in how easy it is to get Haskell to talk to all the existing Windows stuff which exports a COM interface.

Answer (score 2):

[HDirect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdirect) used to be the standard, as it was last uploaded 3 years ago I imagine it's bitrotted a fair bit.

Looks like there's a [new package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/com) aimed at doing the same sorts of things.

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled across references to those two things, but couldn't find any actual _explanation_ as to how you might use them...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm may be a little bit late.

There is already someone who plays with excel:
[Excel Automation with haskell gives a seg fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14537516/572866)

I've written some scripts who communicate with Clearcase and Clearquest.
It was quite easy until I get problems with variant StringArray (look
at my question on SO).

I've used HDirect in order to generate the Haskell glue code. The procedure is:

- launch the OLE/COM Object Viewer and select View Typelib in the File menu
- select the DLL (e.g. ccauto.dll for Clearcase)
- save the IDL file
- run HDirect on this IDL file in order to get the haskell glue code
- import it in your project